# Android Gmail/Email Interactions

Tags: android, receiver

Is there a way to programmatically through an app on the phone monitor for a specific email address that an email was sent to and move it to a new label/folder? This question is for both Gmail apps and the native mail apps. I want basically an external app to run filters.

Thanks!
Phil

Comment: I'm unsure whether this is an attempt to find an app that provides that functionality or if you are looking for a programmatic approach. If you're looking for an app, I'm afraid that this is the wrong forum for that recommendation. If you're looking for a programmatic approach, it _might_ be a bit too broad of a question. Perhaps edit your question and expand it a bit to clarify.

Comment: I am looking to externally filter the email. I want to have a predefined group in this app and if I get an email from one of those people, move the email from inbox to a different label/folder and then play a different notification tone.